# Binding tiles with Rect

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble binding tiles with `Rect`. I've successfully bound other objects (such as the player, trees, etc) in my game with rectangles but I'm unable to do the same with the tiles and I don't know where I'm going wrong. Here's my tile class:

```
public class Tile {
    private float x, y;
    private int type;
    private static int VelX;
    private static int tileSpeed = -200;
    private static Rect tileRect;
    public Bitmap tileImage;

    public Tile (float x, float y, int typeInt) {
        this.x = x * 50;
        this.y = y * 50;
        type = typeInt;
        tileRect = new Rect();

        if (type == 2) {
            tileImage = Assets.grass;
        } else if (type == 1) {
            tileImage = Assets.dirt;
        }
    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        x += VelX * delta;
        tileRect.set((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + 50, (int) y + 50);
    }

    public static void accel() {
        VelX = tileSpeed;
    }

    public static void stop() {
        VelX = 0;
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public static Rect getTileRect() {
        return tileRect;
    }

    public Bitmap getTileImage() {
        return tileImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with binding, so what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Surround the tiles with a rectangle, which I am unable to accomplish

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Collision? What's supposed to happen? What does happen? What's different from your other 'bound' objects? We need more information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using as **non-static** variable:

```
private Rect tileRect;
//...
public Rect getTileRect()
{
    return tileRect;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: can show us, how you initialize the tiles?

Comment: yeah, sure. Have a look at this code http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109733/error-rendering-map-android

Answer (score 0):

I see two things which are probably causing you trouble here.

When you call .set on the rectangle the numbers you enter are used as X position, Y position, width and height. Right now it looks like you are using them like they would represent the other corner of the rectangle.

```
tileRect.set(x, y, 50, 50);
```

This is probably what you are meaning to do.

It's also possible to do this right as you create the rectangle.

```
    tileRect = new Rect(x, y, 50, 50);
```

Also, the rectangle in your code is static, which means that every instance of the class Tile that you make, share the same rectangle. Obviously this will cause problem if you are going to use the class to display several tiles.

You might also not want to set the tiles size in the update method, since that will probably be called every frame, unless you intend to move the tile, in which case you can use:

```
tileRect.setPosition(x, y);
```

That way you don't have to set the size, but only the position.